# Creating a data model from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, datamodel

I have a JSON that looks like this :

```
{
"club": [
    {
        "titles": "1",
        "league": "epl",
        "country": "england",

    }
}
```

And I have created a property like this :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <Clubs> *club;
```

The club property inherits from the Clubs class which has the titles, leagues and country properties.

When I try to create a dictionary with that data model, I am unable to access the properties inside the club array.

Am I creating the data model incorrectly ?

**Creating the dictionary**:

```
        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in responseObject) {

                if (![self.searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
                    self.predictiveProductsSearch = [[PerdictiveSearch alloc]initWithDictionary:dictionary error:nil];
                    self.predictiveTableView.dataSource = self;
                    [self.predictiveTableView reloadData];
                    self.predictiveTableView.hidden = NO;

            }

        }
```

**Clubs class**

```
 #import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>


 @protocol Clubs @end
 @interface Clubs : JSONModel

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * titles;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * league;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * country;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * topGS;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * GoalSc;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString <Optional> * TransferBudget;


@end
```

Comment: First, why you do you need a dictionary ? Second, Kindly post the code where you are doing what you have mentioned.

Comment: @Nitish I'm trying to store the data in a dictionary so I can display it as a predicative search in a tableView

Comment: Show your code for how you are creating  **Clubs** from JSON ?

Comment: Not related but you should name the object model in singular form and the property in plural form. And `Club` is most likely a class so you need to add another asterisk: `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <Club *> *clubs;`.

Comment: @vadian Yeah it would make more sense doing that, I will do that, And I created a "@protocol Club @end" to avoid that issue

Comment: can you post code of Club class ?

Comment: @Vinodh I've added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code to achieve JSON Model saving:

```
_club = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSDictionary *responseObject = @{
    @"club": @[
             @{
                 @"titles": @"1",
                 @"league": @"epl",
                 @"country": @"england"

             }]
             };
NSArray *newResponseObject = [responseObject objectForKey:@"club"];
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in newResponseObject) {

    Clubs *objClubs = [[Clubs alloc]initWithDictionary:dictionary error:nil];
    [_club addObject:objClubs];

}

NSLog(@"%@",[_club objectAtIndex:0]);
```

which print like below :

```
<Clubs> 
   [titles]: 1
   [country]: england
   [GoalSc]: <nil>
   [league]: epl
   [topGS]: <nil>
   [TransferBudget]: <nil>
</Clubs>
```